# Is XSS by html event injection a problem in this client-side sanitization?

Tags: javascript, security

I'm making my own client-side router which dynamically requests html pages from Firebase hosting, and the website uses Cloud Firestore with secure rules. Is there any XSS HTML event js injection danger like so:

`<button onClick = "alert('Some harmful stuff is happening')">Click me!</button>`

If I implement a client-side sanitizer, and is there any danger in general even if I don't sanitize incoming pages since all requests are same origin?

Comment: Hard to say without a complete analysis of your environment.

Comment: What data more specifically would you want me to add?

Comment: It's not that simple.  It "works" if Cloud Firestore secure rules and the client-side sanitizer says it "works" (for some definition of "works").  Are you going to trust them?

Comment: To put your question in perspective, [this](https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/latest/) is what OWASP says is needed to have reasonable confidence that your site is "secure" (for their definition of "secure").